# Hyundai Getz roof antenna mount broke

Tags: hyundai, repair

So, I went to wash the wife's car yesterday, and (as always) struggled with unscrewing the roof antenna from its base. This time, however, the thing broke.

Now I'm thinking, is this something I can replace myself? How do I even get the broken antenna base off the roof (it must be fastened from/to the inside)?

FYI, the image below shows the location of the antenna base between the windshield and roof window.

[image]

Comment: I haven't taken them apart, but would bet you would access the base by taking the roof liner inside the cabin apart. There may be some kind of overhead console there ... if so, you may be able to remove it to gain access to it. Depending on how it broke (was it just the threaded part snapped off inside the base?) will dictate how you will need to fix it. If you need to replace the base portion, you'll have to pull the entire wiring from the radio up to the base portion, then reinstall the new one. Not a lot of fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Paulster2's comment it was an easy decision: let the pros handle it. It ended up costing far less than me wrecking the car and *then* letting the pros handle it...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how skillful you are with a drill, you may be able to drill a hole down the centre of the snapped off ariel that remains stuck in the base.  Then you can use something like a [stud extractor](https://www.machinemart.co.uk/shop/product/details/cht123-screw-extractor-wrench-set) to remove it.

A stud extractor is essentially a reverse-threaded self tapping screw so as you turn it in an anti-clockwise direction it first screws into the hole you have drilled.  It then "bites" and continuing to turn it removed the snapped of piece from the original threads.

The one risk you have here is that if you slip with the drill you may damage the paintwork on the roof of the car.  I would advise using something like a cloth with a piece of wooden board resting on the roof to mitigate against this.  If you inadvertently drill the antenna base at the wrong angle or drill too far, you will have to replace this part which is what you are looking at doing anyway so trying to extract the snapped off piece may be worthwhile provided the cost of a stud extractor kit is less than the replacement part plus your time to fit it.

Comment: Good idea, but sadly -- it's the antenna base that broke. The threaded rod that's broken off is (was) part of the base and is now stuck in the antenna. Your suggestion would have worked if the threaded rod was part of the antenna and stuck in the base...

Comment: Oh dear.  You may be able to use the above technique to remove the snapped off piece from the antenna so you wouldn't have to purchase a new one.  It may be possible to dissemble the base to replace just the broken piece but that very much depends on if these are available separately.

Comment: More likely @KlaymenDK will have to remove the interior headliner and get at the base of the antenna. I'd suggest calling your local dealership and asking for a short description of how to get the antenna mount out and put a new one in. As for finding a new one junkyards and ebay are your friends.